# Geo co-ordinates points plot on wrong location on OSM map using QGIS Python

Tags: pyqgis, openstreetmap

I developing the application to track the location on map based on geo coordinates lat, lon using QGIS Python.

I tried the concept using geo referenced toposheets it showing correct location. But same concept not working on OSM Map and Google map also.

the coordinates showing some where in the map. This lat lon is actual location was Bangalore, India.

But it was showing on OSM Map and Google map near Africa.

[image]

[image]

```
    def load_map(self):
    dialog = self.sender().parent()
    map_service_combo = dialog.findChild(QComboBox)
    selected_map_service = map_service_combo.currentText()
    if selected_map_service == "OpenStreetMap":
        tile_url = "url=http://a.tile.openstreetmap.fr/hot/{z}/{x}/{y}.png&zmax=19&zmin=0&type=xyz"
    elif selected_map_service == "Google Maps":
        tile_url = "type=xyz&zmin=0&zmax=19&url=https://mt1.google.com/vt/lyrs%3Ds%26x%3D{x}%26y%3D{y}%26z%3D{z}"
    else:
        return
    layer = QgsRasterLayer(tile_url, "Satellite Map", "wms")
    if not layer.isValid():
        QMessageBox.warning(self, "Error", "Failed to load satellite map.")
    else:
        # Set the CRS for the layer
        crs = QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem('EPSG:4326')
        layer.setCrs(crs)
        QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(layer)
        self.canvas.setExtent(layer.extent())
        self.canvas.setLayers([layer])
        # Update the CRS label
        self.crs_label.setText("CRS: {}".format(layer.crs().authid()))
        # Close the dialog window
        dialog.accept()


   def plot_coordinates(self):
    # Get the latitude and longitude values from the input fields
    latitude_str = self.latitude_lineedit.text()
    longitude_str = self.longitude_lineedit.text()
    # altitude_str = self.altitude_lineedit.text()

    # Convert the latitude and longitude values to float
    latitude = float(latitude_str)
    longitude = float(longitude_str)
    # altitude = float(altitude_str)

    # Create a point layer
    point_layer = QgsVectorLayer('Point?crs=EPSG:4326', 'Point Layer', 'memory')
    if not point_layer.isValid():
        print('Failed to create point layer')
        return

    # Add latitude and longitude fields to the point layer
    point_layer.dataProvider().addAttributes(
        [QgsField('Latitude', QVariant.Double), QgsField('Longitude', QVariant.Double), QgsField('Altitude',
                                                                                                 QVariant.Double)])
    point_layer.updateFields()

    # Start editing the point layer
    point_layer.startEditing()

    # Create a point feature
    feature = QgsFeature(point_layer.fields())
    feature.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPointXY(QgsPointXY(longitude, latitude)))

    # Set the latitude and longitude attribute values
    feature.setAttribute('Latitude', latitude)
    feature.setAttribute('Longitude', longitude)
    # feature.setAttribute('Altitude', altitude)

    # Commit the changes to the point layer
    point_layer.addFeature(feature)
    point_layer.commitChanges()

    # Get the topographic map layers
    topographic_layers = self.get_topographic_map_layers()

    # Add the point layer to the map canvas
    QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(point_layer)

    # Set the layers on the map canvas
    self.canvas.setLayers([point_layer] + topographic_layers)

def get_topographic_map_layers(self):
    # Get the topographic map layers from the canvas
    layers = self.canvas.layers()

    # Filter out non-raster layers
    topographic_layers = [layer for layer in layers if isinstance(layer, QgsRasterLayer)]

    return topographic_layers
```

above I shared my code.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: If you don't specify the correct projection to start, then your "degree" data is plotted as meters near the origin ("Null Island").